# I am trying to print out a multidimensional array, but it prints out weird memory address?

Tags: c++, arrays

As you can see, I am trying to print out a 2D array but it prints out weird memory addresses! any ideas ! i am new to c++!

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
void display(int array[2][10], int size);


void main() {
    SetConsoleTitleA("Random Number generator!");
    system("Color 3F");
    int Daniel[2][10] = { {20, 32, 43, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2 ,4 ,33}, {23, 54, 2, 5,3,3,6,3,65,3} };
    display(Daniel, 7);
}

void display(int array[2][10], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: `array[i][j]`. Its a multi-dimensional array. need to reference a multidimensional position. Putting an additional forloop around the `std::cout` will allow you to iterate over the whole array, index by index

Answer (score 1):

Your array `Daniel` is 2D array, so if you try to print `array[i]`, it prints an adress. If you want to print the content of the array, you should do it like this:

```
void display(int array[2][10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            std::cout << array[i][j] << std::endl;
}
```

Also, your `main()` function should return `int` instead of `void`, so change `void main()` to `int main()` and `return 0;` at the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the array and the number of rows and columns:

```
#include <iostream>
void displayArray(int a[][10], size_t numRows, size_t numColumns)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
        for (size_t j = 0; j < numColumns; j++){
            std::cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int Daniel[2][10] = { { 20, 32, 43, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 33 }, { 23, 54, 2, 5, 3, 3, 6, 3, 65, 3 } };
    displayArray(Daniel, 2, 10);
    return 0;
}
```